# Why do .dart and .dart.js files appear on the same call stack?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flaky integration test for Flutter Web, which I want to debug. I suspect some Flutter bug, but have no reproducible example to report it. Here is the failed run: https://github.com/apache/beam/actions/runs/5241188101/jobs/9462953674?pr=27100#step:9:207

It reads:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown running a test:
Unexpected null value.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 606:63  nullCheck
packages/playground_components/src/widgets/tabbed_snippet_editor.dart.js 7242:24  _runReal
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1407:47                                              _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1308:19                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 575:7                                         [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 424:15                                             <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1391:47                                              _rootRun
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1301:19                                              run
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1209:7                                               runGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1249:23                                              <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1399:13                                              _rootRun
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1301:19                                              run
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1233:23                                              <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19           internalCallback
```

The only my file in the stack is `packages/playground_components/src/widgets/tabbed_snippet_editor.dart`.
It is also the only one that became `.js`, so I cannot see what exactly triggered the error. This I have never seen before. In my experience, Dart exception stacks are either all `.dart`, or all `.dart.js` if something is misconfigured between the browser and the debugger. Unoptimized `.dart.js` stacks had always been hinting the issue even though line numbers are a bit off, but this time my 85-line .dart file turned into 7242+ lines, which is another indication of something being wrong. Even weirder is that I have no unsafe `!` in that file, so the exception may be from some larger construct inlined.

At this point my main questions are: What causes a file to show as `.dart` or `.dart.js` on an exception stack? Is there anything I can do to make it `.dart` and see the offending line?

The sub-question is how to see the `.dart.js` source from the integration test? Chrome does not show it.

I run my integration tests the way that [the documentation prescribes it for web](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#5b-web).

The offending file, it it matters: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/95668013cae00a18418f1bafa08015d7cee05c54/playground/frontend/playground_components/lib/src/widgets/tabbed_snippet_editor.dart

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a Dart app in a browser means running it in a JavaScript engine, so the Dart code has to first be compiled to JavaScript. This is done through the dart2js tool, which is itself written in Dart and lives in the bin subfolder of dart-sdk. The tool is also nicely integrated in Dart Editor.

[Official Doc](https://dart.dev/web)

So, if you write some native js code in a web channel that's the `.js` files you have, but the `.dart` files will be also compiled to js.

And the last question I don't know how to see that transpiled code, I also looked for the kotlin transpilation code and never found it.

Comment: I know that by the end of the day it is .js that runs. But most of the time the debugging information is there, so in the stack we can see .dart files and line numbers in them even in web. The question is how that can be influenced and enforced.